# Generate menu tags html by for statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can i generate html tags below  that represent sidemenu in webpage by "for loop",or "foreach blade", or if any one can help me and generate it by" for php  statement" just ?

don't worry about text between tags i want just generate html tags ?

thanks

```
<ul class="sidebar">
    <li>tb
        <ul>
            <li>er
                <ul>
                    <li>cc</li>
                    <li>zz</li>
                    <li>xx</li>
                    <li>mm</li>
                    <li>xx</li>
                    <li>ll</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>BB
        <ul>
            <li>AA</li>
            <li>FF
                <ul>
                    <li>DD</li>
                    <li>TT</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: dont understand what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

One of the coolest and most underused features of laravel are the [Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html) objects.

Below is a pretty detailed answer, however I have gone over it in more detail in my [clean menu management in laravel 4](http://matthewhailwood.co.nz/clean-menu-management-in-laravel-4/) blog post.

This allows you to define your menu as such:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

//define the top level menu
$menu = new Collection;

//each sub menu is it's own collection
$tb = new Collection;

//even sub sub menus
$er = new Collection;
//each link get's pushed onto the relevant menu
$er->push((object)['title' => 'cc', 'link' => URL::route('cc'), 'type' => 'link']);
$er->push((object)['title' => 'zz', 'link' => URL::route('zz'), 'type' => 'link']);
$er->push((object)['title' => 'xx', 'link' => URL::route('xx'), 'type' => 'link']);
$er->push((object)['title' => 'mm', 'link' => URL::route('mm'), 'type' => 'link']);
$er->push((object)['title' => 'xx', 'link' => URL::route('xx'), 'type' => 'link']);
$er->push((object)['title' => 'll', 'link' => URL::route('ll'), 'type' => 'link']);

//sub sub menu's get pushed onto the parent menu
$tb->push((object)['title' => 'er', 'menu' => $er, 'type' => 'menu']);

//sub menu's get pushed onto the main menu object
$menu->push((object)['title' => 'tb', 'menu' => $tb, 'type' => 'menu']);

//define and push the menu's in the order you want them to appear
$BB = new Collection;
$BB->push((object)['title' => 'AA', 'link' => URL::route('AA'), 'type' => 'link']);

$FF = new Collection;
$FF->push((object)['title' => 'DD', 'link' => URL::route('DD'), 'type' => 'link']);
$FF->push((object)['title' => 'TT', 'link' => URL::route('TT'), 'type' => 'link']);
$BB->push((object)['title' => 'FF', 'menu' => $FF, 'type' => 'menu']);
$menu->push((object)['title' => 'BB', 'menu' => $BB, 'type' => 'menu']);
```

I would suggest that the above code be put in a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers).

This gives a great separation of your menu's logic from the actual structure, this can of course all be automated from a database or similar if your menu is not hard coded. But now onto displaying the actual menu! Mote that the below code will generate a valid menu for twitter bootstrap 3. Also there are a couple of extra options such as dividers and disabled menu entries which should give you an idea of how to extend this.

You could probably get away with dropping the `'type' => 'link'` and switching it out in the view below for `@if(!isset($item->type))` but I personally like to be a bit explicit.

Also note that the below code only supports 2 levels, so for your purpose would need to be extended a little bit, possibly even refactored into a recursive function, but I'm not a fan of > 2 levels of menu (and twbs3 doesn't support them anyway) so I don't do that.

```
<nav class="col-xs-6 col-sm-10">
  <div class="row nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      @foreach($menu->all() as $item)
        @if($item->type === 'link')
          <li class="@if(isset($item->disabled))disabled@endif">
            <a href="{{ $item->link }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
          </li>
        @elseif($item->type === 'menu')
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              {{ $item->title }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              @foreach($item->menu->all() as $subItem)
                @if($subItem->type === 'link' && isset($subItem->disabled))
                  <li class="disabled">
                    <a href="#">{{ $subItem->title }}</a>
                  </li>
                @elseif($subItem->type === 'link')
                  <li>
                    <a href="{{ $subItem->link }}">{{ $subItem->title }}</a>
                  </li>
                @elseif($subItem->type === 'divider')
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                @endif
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </li>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="sidebar">
    <?php foreach ($whatever as $whatevr){ ?>
    <li><?=$whatevr?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

that's the basic format. I'm not sure what you're going for exactly, the formatting of your code makes it tough to read.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using blade

```
<ul>
@foreach($items as $item)
<li>{{$item}}</li>
    @if (count($item->children)>0))
        <?php $children = $item->children?>
        <ul>
        @foreach($children as $child)
            <li>{{$child}}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in jQuery you can achieve this without PHP with some cool effects of all sorts. Example with fade in:

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4PEm9/)**

```
 var list = $('#theList li:last-child'),
    limit = 20,
    current = 0;

function rand() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // Just for some random contnt
}

$('#trigger').click(function() { // We're using a static button to start the population of the list
            var end = setInterval(function() {
            if ( current == limit ) {
                current = 0;
                clearInterval(end);
            }
            var elm = $('<li style="display:none;color:green;">' + rand() + '</li>');
            list = elm.insertAfter(list);               
            elm.fadeIn();
            var colorEnd = setInterval(function() {
                    elm.css('color', 'black');
                    clearInterval(colorEnd);
            }, 350);
            current =  current + 1;
        }, 300);
});
```

Here we establish the last `<li>` in our container with `$('#theList li:last-child')`, and then start a loop, appending after our new `<li>` as well as random content. We display it hidden in order to then re-establish the last `<li>` with `$('#theList li:last-child')` again in a new variable,  and use `.fadeIn()` function for a nice effect.